# docker - dangling (None) intermediate image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, credentials

I have dockerfile that builds one intermediate image, which uses sensitive data to pull up code from private repository.

So having such Dockerfile content:

```
FROM alpine/git:v2.26.2 as intermediate

ARG SSH_PRIVATE_KEY
RUN mkdir /root/.ssh/ && chmod 755 /root/.ssh
RUN echo "${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}" > /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 && chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
# Generate public key from private key.
RUN ssh-keygen -y -f /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 > /root/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub

# make sure your domain is accepted
RUN touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts && chmod 644 /root/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN ssh-keyscan github.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts

RUN git clone -b master --single-branch git@github.com:user/my-repo.git /root/my-repo

FROM main_image

# Do some stuff
COPY --from=intermediate /root/my-repo /mnt/my-repo
# Do some stuff more...
# ....
# ....
CMD ["my_cmd"]
```

**Question:** after image is built from that Dockerfile, I also get dangling None image (assuming its coming from intermediate image). `docker images`, outputs that `None` image (there are also lots of `None` images which are showed by `docker images -a`, but those I know are expected). Is it expected to always occur and I should just delete it, or am I doing something wrong here and I should not get dangling image after building my image?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you are correct that if you see 'none:none' when you run 'docker images -a' these are the intermediate images which get re-used later using cached layers

When you see the 'none:none' images when running the 'docker images' command, these are images which are dangling and no longer used - therefore should be pruned to preserve disk space

This site explains it fairly well - https://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2015/07/what-are-docker-none-none-images/.

It uses an example of pulling down a Fedora base image to run the 'hello-world' image (meaning 2 images were created - an intermediate one for Fedora and the output image for our hello-world app)

If you rebuilt the hello-world image a month later and a new version of Fedora is available, the new Fedora image is pulled leaving the old intermediate Fedora image dangling (with none:none) and it then just takes up disk space